# access remote program files folder using C#

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

I'm attempting to grab version info of software installed on remote PCs. This is simple on local machines, but WMI doesn't seem to allow for this. Ideally I would like to reach out to the remote PCs with something like this:

```
scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", name), options);
        scope.Connect();
//somehow set environment to remote PC
path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + @"\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
```

Comment: are you trying to get the version of a specific product that's installed on a remote machine using WMI...? if so perhaps this link can help [C# WMI Access Software](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx) or this google search [C# WMI Access Software Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20WMI%20access%20software%20version%20located%20on%20a%20remote%20pc)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I'll read through the links you posted.